# Edit local user account remotely: set passwordreq:yes

Tags: windows, command-line-interface, user-management, group-policy, batch

I'm using

Net user username /passwordreq:yes

but I need to do this on a bunch of machines. I can run a batch through SCCM, but would like to do it with a script. Anyone have a way to do this?

Thanks!
-Mathew

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**If all of the computers are turned on:**

Download and install [PSExec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx), create a file with each of your workstations on a line of their own, you can do this with Active Directory users and Computers search quite easily. Then run the following command:

```
psexec @filename.txt -s net user username /passwordreq:yes
```

**If the computers are not turned on:**

put

```
net user username /passwordreq:yes
```

into a .cmd file and add it as a computer startup script in Group Policy - this is pretty much the same thing as using SCCM.

Comment: I'll check out psexec when I get back to work. No can do on the GP since I don't control it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a script, here's a quick VBS script that should do it for you:

```
Const ADS_UF_PASSWD_NOTREQD = &H0020
strDCHostName = "myDC" 'Change this value to the name of your domain controller
strUserName = "jsmith" 'Change this value to the username in question
set objUser = GetObject("WinNT://" & strDCHostName & "/" & strUserName)
objPwdNotRequiredFlag = objUserFlags AND NOT ADS_UF_PASSWD_NOTREQD
objuser.put "userFlags",objPwdNotRequiredFlag
objUser.SetInfo
```

Comment: Does this set it for the local user on the remote machine? look like it's making this change in AD.